# Linewrap in Org-mode of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Does Org-mode of Emacs support linewrapping?

I know in the "regular" mode of Emacs there will just be a little sideways-u-turn on the right and on the left on the line after, and there's no scrolling necessary.

However, there are only arrows pointing left and right.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The default mode for org-mode is truncate-lines mode.

You can customize this behaviour with `org-startup-truncated`. Type `F1-v org-startup-truncated` for a description, and then click on the customize link to change it.

Comment: thanks - I just set it to "nil" by going <CTL>-h v: org-startup truncated.

Comment: for one-off, evaluating the following expression did the trick for me: (setq truncate-lines 'nil)

Comment: In general, in any emacs mode, the function toggle-truncate-lines, will toggle back and forth (for a temporary solution)

Comment: Do you know the reason why `truncate-lines` is the default? Given that org mode is for taking notes instead of programming, long lines must be the norm

Comment: @Heisenberg I think the reason for the default is that org-mode tables look really bad when word-wrapped.

Comment: @superdesk this is maybe worth another question, but isn't it possible to `truncate-lines` only for those lines containing org-mode tables?

Answer (score 36):

You can also toggle it on-the-fly with the command `toggle-truncate-lines`, between the normal Emacs view and the normal org view. For example, use this:

```
(define-key org-mode-map "\M-q" 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

M-q is bound to fill-paragraph by default, but probably you don't want to use it within org-mode.

Answer (score 13):

Org mode does not wrap lines on purpose, to not make tables appear very ugly. The function `org-fill-paragraph` controls the insertions of line breaks for one paragraph for you. So you might want to use that instead of line wrapping.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding (global-visual-line-mode t) to your init file.

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode